# ¿Pueden encontrar el error de ordenamiento en este codigo de MergeSort?

Tags: c++, array, ordenamiento, recursión, ordenar

somos un equipo universitarios, necesitamos ayuda en un proyecto, estamos creando un proyecto que se basa en un organizador de tareas, las tareas llevan titulo, descripcion y fecha de vencimiento, estas se guardan en un .txt, el problema viene cuando se imprime en la consola, esta no lo ordena de forma correcta (La cual seria que imprimiera primero las tareas mas cercanas a vences, y hasta el ultimo serian las tareas mas alejadas de vencer), suponiendo que se registran 3 tareas, las muestra de la siguiente forma:
1-La ultima a vencer
2-La primera a vencer
3-La de enmedio a vencer

Claramente deberia ser:
1-La primera a vencer
2-La de enmedio a vencer
3-La ultima en vencer

Alguien ve el error? Porfa :(
Esto llevamos del codigo:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
struct Tareas{
string Nombre, Descripcion, FechaVencimiento;
};
char opc;

void Registro(){
system("cls");
cin.ignore();
ofstream archivo;
archivo.open("Tareas.txt", ios::app);
do{
    Tareas NuevaTarea;
    cout << "¿Cómo se llama la tarea?"<<endl;
    getline(cin, NuevaTarea.Nombre);

    cout << "Agrega una descripción para la tarea: "<<endl;
    getline(cin, NuevaTarea.Descripcion);

    cout << "¿Cuándo se tiene que entregar? (YYYY/MM/DD)"<<endl;
    getline(cin, NuevaTarea.FechaVencimiento);

    if(archivo.is_open()){
        archivo << "Nombre: " << NuevaTarea.Nombre << "\n";
        archivo << "Descripción: " << NuevaTarea.Descripcion << "\n";
        archivo << "Fecha de Vencimiento: " << NuevaTarea.FechaVencimiento << "\n";
        archivo << " " << "\n";

        cout << "La tarea ha sido guardada con éxito\n" <<endl;
    }else{
        cerr << "Error al guardar la tarea\n" <<endl;
    }

    cout << "¿Deseas agregar otra tarea? [y/n]" <<endl;
    cin >> opc;
    cin.ignore();

    system("cls");
}while (opc == 'y' || opc == 'Y');
system("cls");
archivo.close();
}

bool compararFechas(const Tareas& tarea1, const Tareas& tarea2) {
return tarea1.FechaVencimiento < tarea2.FechaVencimiento;
}

void leerTareas(vector<Tareas>& tareas) {
ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
Tareas tarea;

while (getline(archivo, tarea.Nombre)) {
    getline(archivo, tarea.Descripcion);
    getline(archivo, tarea.FechaVencimiento);
    archivo.ignore();
    tareas.push_back(tarea);
}

archivo.close();
}

void ordenarTareasPorFecha(vector<Tareas>& tareas, int inicio, int final) {
if (inicio < final) {
    int mitad = inicio + (final - inicio) / 2;
    ordenarTareasPorFecha(tareas, inicio, mitad);
    ordenarTareasPorFecha(tareas, mitad + 1, final);

    // Merge adaptado para comparar por fecha de vencimiento
    int i = inicio;
    int j = mitad + 1;
    vector<Tareas> temporal;

    while (i <= mitad && j <= final) {
        if (compararFechas(tareas[i], tareas[j])) {
            temporal.push_back(tareas[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            temporal.push_back(tareas[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }

    while (i <= mitad) {
        temporal.push_back(tareas[i]);
        i++;
    }

    while (j <= final) {
        temporal.push_back(tareas[j]);
        j++;
    }

    // Copiar los elementos ordenados de vuelta al vector original
    for (int k = 0; k < temporal.size(); k++) {
        tareas[inicio + k] = temporal[k];
    }
}
}


void Lista(){
system("cls");
cin.ignore();
string tarea;
ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
cout << "Mostrando lista de tareas registradas...\n\n";

while(getline(archivo, tarea)){
    cout << tarea << endl;
}
system("pause");
system("cls");
archivo.close();
}

void Busqueda(){
system("cls");
cin.ignore();
string Clave;
Tareas tarea;

cout << "Ingresa la palabra clave: "<< endl;
getline(cin, Clave);

ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
while(getline(archivo, tarea.Nombre)){
    getline(archivo, tarea.Descripcion);
    getline(archivo, tarea.FechaVencimiento);

    if(tarea.Descripcion.find(Clave) != -1){
        cout << tarea.Nombre <<endl;
        cout << tarea.Descripcion <<endl;
        cout << tarea.FechaVencimiento <<endl;
    }
}
system("pause");
system("cls");
}

void Merge(vector<int>&arreglo, int inicio, int mitad, int final){
int i,j,k;
int elementosizq = mitad - inicio + 1;
int elementosder = final - mitad;

vector<int>izquierda(elementosizq);
vector<int>derecha(elementosder);

for(int i = 0; i < elementosizq; i++){
    izquierda[i] = arreglo[inicio+i];
}
for(int j = 0; j < elementosder; j++){
    derecha[j] = arreglo[mitad + 1 + j];
}

i = 0;
j = 0;
k = inicio;

while(i < elementosizq && j < elementosder){
    if(izquierda[i] <= derecha[j]){
        arreglo[k] = izquierda[i];
        i++;
    }else {
        arreglo[k] = derecha[j];
        j++;
    }
    k++;
}

while(j < elementosder){
    arreglo[k] = derecha[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}

while(i < elementosizq){
    arreglo[k] = izquierda[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}


}

void MergeSort(vector<int>&arreglo, int inicio, int final){
if(inicio < final){
    int mitad = inicio + (final - inicio)/2;
    MergeSort(arreglo, inicio, mitad);
    MergeSort(arreglo, mitad+1,final);
    Merge(arreglo,inicio,mitad,final);
}
}

void imprimirArreglo(vector<int>arreglo){
for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.size(); i++){
    cout << arreglo[i] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
}

bool continuar = true;

int main(){
char opcion;
Tareas tarea;
ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
do {
    cout << "Menu de opciones:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Crear Tareas" << endl;
    cout << "2. Mostrar lista de tareas" << endl;
    cout << "3. Ordenar tareas (por fecha)" << endl;
    cout << "4. Búsqueda de tareas" << endl;
    cout << "5. Planificación de tareas" << endl;
    cout << "6. Salir" << endl;
    cout << "¿Qué desea hacer?" << endl;
    cin >> opcion;

    switch (opcion) {
        case '1':
            Registro();
            break;
        case '2':
            Lista();
            break;
        case '4':
            Busqueda();
            break;
        case '3':
            vector<Tareas> tareas;
            leerTareas(tareas);
            ordenarTareasPorFecha(tareas, 0, tareas.size() - 1);
            cout << "Tareas ordenadas por fecha de vencimiento:\n";
            for (const auto &tarea : tareas) {
                cout << tarea.Nombre << endl;
                cout << tarea.Descripcion << endl;
                cout << tarea.FechaVencimiento << endl;
                cout << "------------------------\n";
            }
            break;
    }
} while (continuar);

cout << "Presiona Enter para salir" << endl;
cin.ignore();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estaría bien que subas el código de `Ordenar` para ver qué intentaste y ayudarte a partir de lo que ya tienes.

Comment: Ordenar solo era un nombre que le puse al MergeSort en realidad ;-;

Answer (score 0):

El código de la [segunda edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/609182/2) funciona perfectamente. Todo lo que tienes que hacer son pequeñas modificaciones para que pueda trabajar con elementos de cualquier tipo.

Por ejemplo, puedes introducir una función como parámetro que realice la comparación entre 2 elementos. Así:

```
template <typename T>
void Merge(vector<T>&arreglo, function<bool(const T&, const T&)> menorOIgual, int inicio, int mitad, int final){
    ...

    while(i < elementosizq && j < elementosder){
        if(menorOIgual(izquierda[i], derecha[j])){
            arreglo[k] = izquierda[i];
            i++;
        }else {
            arreglo[k] = derecha[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    ...
}

template <typename T>
void MergeSort(vector<T>& arreglo, function<bool(const T&, const T&)> menorOIgual, int inicio, int final){
    if(inicio < final){
        int mitad = inicio + (final - inicio)/2;
        MergeSort(arreglo, menorOIgual, inicio, mitad);
        MergeSort(arreglo, menorOIgual, mitad+1,final);
        Merge(arreglo, menorOIgual, inicio,mitad,final);
    }
}
```

Así se utilizaría en tu código:

```
vector<Tareas> tareas;

function<bool(const Tareas&, const Tareas&)> menorOIgual = [](const Tareas &a, const Tareas &b) {
    // Aquí puedes escribir la lógica necesaria para comparar las 2 fechas
};

MergeSort(tareas, menorOIgual, 0,prueba.size() - 1);
```

[Aquí](https://tio.run/##tVRLj5swEL77V4yohEBh290eFzZSjz1UPTS3KAfHmKwJYGrMVm3Eb0/HGAxhs9leioQf8/jmm7HHrK7vDoydzx9ExYo25ZAI2WjFabkmk@yFMy3VXII2ojrMJVlbMS1kRYs1IW2DWqhoyZuaMg6NTmNCNC/rgmo01r9rbrSwWZMXKVL4xtWBBzZOsln7VCl@KGQEI2yyl7IImKwaDRs/gnEVrqHklVTfvx5aWkQgKo2/YELadSk0Te0yE0guPJHeJMqjY9wvecERQctG/PkJT9YB7gYQWMHDwizlCs16MDTrzTE3Rx1RWsFVSoM5cBhPFgjA2fNMjwLUk0yqoOeG8PcxTskFN5SsVkgf8HNBtmKH1kO1tpbzSuxi0jm43MLlcziMiBIHNzDa5nMwWwjMH/@8RySWGbGI5IiTjYjkfz2LggdLzuD7rwKPKWTB7OCCeUbRjFA4mJtvZHY0NOcOsTPBEtlNx4uGwxu@E/zkmTvPfjyabTfm9UYON0Ed4CXUskTXoF7nJpZgxAzvNdQPqfT/aCrXSVkwtEniZD3bsfHcDcE7FIwtYyXhp882o4mp47cIbgP3gOG/@fS2q4fIkpr53I5hH4vRqXunxKKslSiF@mIhp0KPh4nVuNLTg/IjHj4PwnlXM9lqSJKpnXdm54FnuIxKXqWFbUZTZCqqwHoP0YeHGWrV8j3FqCcv9yLwUjPszUDNwMyQeV1fmmUi1tc8SajEp/vx8dqFsZHcrRm2l1cH4293F/bg00sP8PchnEBx3aoKKCRPsI/BEpuO2VJanNp9ZMVDKfFqPYS3E0LdEAjfr@58/gs) tienes un ejemplo comparando 2 strings.

Comment: Si, gracias por el apoyo :)